# IntelliJ and Application Server log

Tags: intellij-idea

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I cannot seem to get back the log view of the application server if once has been closed.

After deploying my app, the log view works fine, but if I accidentally close the tab (which happens quite often for some reason) it only displays the following:

[image]

Is there not a way to get this tab back without a full re-deploy of the app?

This is such a silly thing but it bugs me so regularly that I decided to ask this here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the exact same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

On Toolbar, Click View -> Tool Windows -> Android. 
It will give many other options like event log, terminal etc. Give it a try.

Comment: Tool Windows is the first place I looked.  The application server log is under "Run", and if I go View -> Tool Windows -> Run it will only bring up what is shown in the screenshot I posted, if I've closed the log view.  There is no other option in View that will bring back the log view.

Answer (score 0):

Alt-4 (Or View > Tool Windows > run)